# Tried all the advice I could find, still can't get child elements to stay in the parent

Tags: html, css-float, css

So I've tried everything that's been discussed and used to solve this on every site (overflow:hidden/overflow:auto/clear:both/height:auto;parent is relative; child is absolute) And I've finally given in into creating a stackoverflow account.

I just can't seem to keep my text inside my parent container.  I swear it's just something super small that I'm forgetting.

Here's a JSFiddle of it..

http://jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/15/

HTML

```
<div id="red">
<h1 class="whiteHeading">Headline</h1>
    <h2 class="whiteP"> SubHead</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#red{
    background-color: #cc0033; 
    overflow:auto; 
    position:relative; 
    min-height: 75px; 
    clear:both;}
#red h1{
    position: absolute; 
    left:25px;top: 0px;
    font-size: 18px; }
#red h2{
    position: absolute; 
    left:25px;
    top: 75px; 
    width: 250px;}
#red p{
    color: FFFFFF;}
```

I've added a min-height to the parent it just so I can tell whether or not the parent extends to include both childs.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't stay in the parent container? All the text is in the parent container as far as I can see. Remove the `overflow: auto` from `#redband` and the `position: absolute; top:..; left:..;` from the `h2` and `h3`.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/16/  <--  This is the suggestion made by putvande.

Comment: oh wow. so what exactly was causing my problems? adding absolute position to my h1/h2?

Comment: Absolute positioning will put objects on top of one another if needed, overflow was hiding your h2 tags because your positioning in the div was causing them to be relative (which is not placing them on top of one another). Pretty much it was a contradiction. If you could check my answer as right that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of relative positioning is to place multiple objects by one another without actually having them overlap. Your div is causing a contradiction and making your h2 tags go out of the div because of the positioning and then the overflow hiding it all together. Here is the JS Fiddle that paints a better picture: jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/16

Comment: Here is a useful website as well to help with other CSS needs :) http://css-tricks.com/almanac/